# Shape outside to take full height of text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up a shape outside image to a text, however the image never cover the full height of text :

[image: image not covering full text]

As you can see, I am trying to get a tank, but it doesn't work.

I have tried to add two images (with 100% height) on the left and right of the text, but it doesn't fill the height of the text.

```css
#parent>img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .2;
}

#a {
  shape-outside: url("...");
  float: left;
}

#b {
  shape-outside: url("...");
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img id="a" src="...">
  <img id="b" src="...">
  <p> Some Text </p>
</div>
```

I want to get a tank for the text in the end, is it possible ?

Comment: Not regarding your question, but: an ID must start with a char, numbers are not allowed.

Comment: @MichaelB. OK I changed it, it was just to simplify the code